# Combine sequential array with associative array in order

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

How to combine sequential array with associative array in order:

Example:

```
$sequentialArray = [123, 'Jonh'];
$associativeArray = ['ID' => '321', 'name' => 'Paul', 'lastName' => 'Wood'];

mergeArray($sequentialArray, $associativeArray);
```

**Return:**

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 123
    [name] => Jonh
    [lastName] => Wood
)
```

Comment: I just edited over your edit I think...did you mean to add a `lastname` value? That changes the question a bit

Comment: Yes, sorry. But wanted it that way.

Comment: Consider editing my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$sequentialArray  = [ 123, 'Jonh'];
$associativeArray = ['ID' => '321', 'name' => 'Paul', 'lastName' => 'Wood'];

$keys = array_slice(
    array_keys($associativeArray),
    0,
    count($sequentialArray)
);

print_r(
    array_merge(
        $associativeArray,
        array_combine($keys, $sequentialArray)
    )
);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [ID] => 123
    [name] => Jonh
    [lastName] => Wood
)
```

**Further reading:** [*Array functions* @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

---

**UPDv1:**

Here is function:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$sequentialArray  = [ 123, 'Jonh'];
$associativeArray = ['ID' => '321', 'name' => 'Paul', 'lastName' => 'Wood'];

function mergeArray($assoc, $seq){
    $keys = array_slice(array_keys($assoc), 0, count($seq));

    return array_merge($assoc, array_combine($keys, $seq));
}

print_r(mergeArray($associativeArray, $sequentialArray));
?>
```

Comment: hmm .. that's better.

Comment: @HAL9000 hello. I want to know what's the use of `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');` ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnRobertson It's for debugging in plain-text mode - useful, when you going to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of large data-structure in none-HTML mode. Try to run it as a pure php script in browser - you'll get readable response, like `<pre>[code]</pre>` in HTML-mode. In a short, it's just a snippet.

Comment: @HAL9000 Thank you. I'll apply it in my future debugging :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$sequentialArray = [123, 'Jonh'];
$associativeArray = ['ID' => '321', 'name' => 'Paul', 'lastName' => 'Wood'];
$newArr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($associativeArray as $key=>$val){
    if(isset($sequentialArray[$i])){
        $newArr[$key] = $sequentialArray[$i];
    }else{
        $newArr[$key] = $val;
    }
    $i++;
 }
```

**Output:**

```
 Array
 (
    [ID] => 123
    [name] => Jonh
    [lastName] => Wood
 )

 print_r($newArr);
```